# RecyclerView always empty after coming back from other fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have set certain condition about when to fetch data from the internet, if the last time fetching data is more than 10 minutes ago, then fetch data from the internet, So i don't need to fetch data over and over again when coming back from other fragment. I wrote this code in`onResume` ,

I assume the product data will still be on my RecyclerView after coming back from other fragment.

If the last time fetching data is more than 10 minutes ago, then I can populate the RecyclerView view with the product data like this :-

[image]

But problem is, when i move from Home Fragment to other fragment, For example if tap other tab in the bottom navigation menu, RecyclerView seems empty, it just text view that appear on the screen like this. (If I back again to the home fragment, it means the last time I fetch product data from server is not more than 10 minutes ago)

[image]

the toolbar and the bottom navigation are part of my Main Activity, so I change fragment in the center part

is my problem because of the `onDestroy` and `onDetach` of my `HomeFragment` is activated when I change to other fragment ?

what went wrong in here ? 
here is the simplified code of my Home Fragment

```
class HomeFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    lateinit var mContext : Context
    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity

    lateinit var recyclerView1 : RecyclerView
    lateinit var fragmentView : View

    private var firstProducts = listOf<Product>()
    lateinit var firstProductAdapter : ProductListAdapter

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // set up view
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        recyclerView1 = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_1)


        return fragmentView
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if (lastTimeFetchDataIsMoreThan10MinutesAgo) {
            getProducts()  // when I open the app for the very first time, I fetch the product data
        } else {

           // when it is more than 10 minutes, do nothing

        }


    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE // to ensure the progress bar will always dissapear if move to another destination

    }

    private fun getProducts(type: String) {

        showProgressBar(true)

        Product.getProductsFromServer(customerID = userData.id.toString(), type = type) { errorMessage, products ->

            errorMessage?.let {
                activity?.toast(it)
            } ?: run {

                val productList = products ?: ArrayList()
                setUpRecyclerView(type = type,products = productList)

            }

        }

        showProgressBar(false)

    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(type: String, products: List<Product>) {
        val productAdapter = ProductListAdapter(context = mContext,products = products)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)


        if (type == "special") {
            firstProductAdapter = productAdapter
            firstProducts = products
            recyclerView1.adapter = productAdapter
            recyclerView1.layoutManager = layoutManager
            recyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true)

        } 

    }

    private fun showProgressBar(enable: Boolean) {

        if (enable) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recyclerView1.visibility = View.GONE
            selectedProductTextView.visibility = View.GONE
            bestSellingProductTextView.visibility = View.GONE

        } else {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            recyclerView1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            selectedProductTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            bestSellingProductTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: have you tried with setting recycleview with old data . when time < 10 min ?

Comment: Try moving your data into a view model

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel

Comment: @TejasPandya I don't understand what you mean with old data :(

Comment: @user8159708 could I possibly why I need to use live data for this problem ? I am sorry, I am a beginner in Android development

Comment: by old data means . the data received first time

Comment: I try to use the product data in property private var firstProducts , but it seems after move to other fragment than back to HomeFragment, the firstProduct list become empty. is this because onDestroy ? I believe that I have assigned the firstProduct property with some product data, so I can't use the "old data"

Comment: A view model just holds data that a view uses. The benefit is that if a fragment or activity is destroyed and recreated (which may be happening when you are switching fragments), normally the data is lost. However if the view holder has the data, it persists and can be re presented to the view.